# How to update to Sharepoint 2013 SP1 and SQL Server SP2

Tags: sharepoint-server, upgrade, sql-server-2012, bi

I have, on my developer machine, a SharePoint 2013 with SQL Server 2012(Sp1 + CU6),
mainly I focus on BI features.

How to upgrade SharePoint to SP1 and SQL Server to SP2?

Which Service pack should be install first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really doesn't matter which SP you installed First, Rather you have to take the appropriate measure before install the any SP.

For Installing SQL Server SP2, you should shut down the all SharePoint Services so that No connection made to SQL from SharePoint while you updating the SQL Server. We shut down the SharePoint Completely while we applied the SPs on the SQL server 5 months ago.

For SharePoint SP, You should do the following way.

- take the backup of your farm(incase of corruption you can recover it.)
- install the Bits(on all Server)
- Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard on all server in farm
- Test and test and test

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 SP1 you can install by executing the Installer. Once completed you need to run the SharePoint 2013 product configuration wizard.

More on this http://blog.fpweb.net/how-to-install-sharepoint-2013-service-pack-1/#.VGoh4fnF9-E

Comment: Which service pack do i have to install first ?

Comment: SQL first then SharePoint. SharePoint service pack should be installed on all Servers in the farm